# Send Data from Activity to TabLayout fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am designing a application in which i am facing problem,

I have a **String date;** in **MainActivity.class** and there are two fragments.

**InboundDate** & **OutboundDate**

I designed it by TabLayout & ViewPager, I am getting issue when i sending date to fragments & have to call  WebServices by POST request on both the fragments.

Below is the date i have in MainActivity.class, How i send this date to both the fragments & call jsonRequest and set Recyclerview to both the fragments Or if i call the jsonRequest to MainActivity itself then how can i display to both the fragments.

```
 date = getIntent().getStringExtra("DATE");
    Log.e("DATE",""+date);
```

ViewPager & TabLayout Code:

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new InBoundDate(),"INBOUND");
    adapter.addFrag(new OutBoundDate(),"OUTBOUND");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

//viewPager adapter ----- inbound & outbound
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer of this question by searching over the internet.
In this question i have to send string to **MainActivity.java** to fragments present on same Activity.

**Note :** We have to create bundle object & have to send string(any dataType) by bundle.

I have two fragments **InBoundDate** & **OutBoundDate**.

In **MainActivity.java** in setupViewpager ()

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    //bundle
    bundle =new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("DATE","2017-10-19");

    InBoundDate frag_in = new InBoundDate();
    OutBoundDate frag_out = new OutBoundDate();

    frag_in.setArguments(bundle);
    frag_out.setArguments(bundle);
    adapter.addFrag(frag_in,"INBOUND");
    adapter.addFrag(frag_out,"OUTBOUND");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

**ViewPager Adapter :**

```
  //viewPager adapter ----- inbound & outbound
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

In your **Fragments** get String by this way :

```
    String dateTxt;
    private Bundle bundle;

    //within OncreateView
     bundle = this.getArguments();
        dateTxt = bundle.getString("DATE");
        Log.e("DATE_FRAG_INBOUND",""+dateTxt);
```

Comment: Well explained!

Comment: Thanks @DanyKamuhanda