# Fragment retrieve data from recycler view

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview

This is an adapter for my `RecyclerView`. It is meant to pass data from the `RecyclerView` to my `Fragment`, but I'm not able to do that from the `onClick()` method.

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putString("name",name.getText().toString() );
       OneFragment myFrag = new OneFragment();
       myFrag.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

My Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    txt_name=(TextView) txt_name.findViewById(R.id.name_emp);
    String name = getArguments().getString("name");
    txt_name.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: We can't call directly  to fragment by adapter OneFragment myFrag = new OneFragment(); First you have to call the fragment's Activity , I have edited my Answer check @joker_7

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you intending to do. But after you set a bundle to a fragment you have to start the fragment with a transaction like this

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(<id of the container>, myFrag).commit();
```

Look the documentation on [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Like Below code create a method to your Activity, Where you have fragment :

**Recyclerview Adapter Code :**

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ((MainActivity)context).sendData(name.getText().toString());
}
```

Get String in your MainActivity and call Fragment from Activity :

**MainActivity Code :**

```
 String name;

 public void sendData(String nameAdapter)
{
    name = nameAdapter;
    if(name!=null){
        MedicineFragment med_frag = MedicineFragment.newInstance(name);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, med_frag)
                .commit();
    }

}
```

get name of Name in your fragment like this :

**Fragment Code :**

```
String name;

public static MedicineFragment newInstance(String nameValue) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    MedicineFragment fragment = new MedicineFragment();
    name = nameValue;
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

inside your main_activity.xml you have to take FrameLayout , by only this layout your fragment will change one to another.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_layout"
        android:background="@color/blue_veryLight"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame">
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: what is content_frame !!

Comment: Inside your activity.xml you have to take @joker_7, I have edited my code please check

Comment: does viewpager replace FrameLayout ?

Comment: No, Do you have to send data to ViewPager Activity's Fragment, am i right ?

Comment: First send data to your Activity where you have done your code of TabActivity and  than send to fragment. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46828366/8448886

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am late to the party. Still, I'll post an answer here.

In your adapter class make these changes.

```
public class FooAdapter extends extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FooAdapter.FooHolder> {

    private RvClickListener mClickListener;
    ......
    // rest of the code here
    ......

    public FooAdapter(<other parameters>, RvClickListener clickListener) {
       .....
       // other variables initializations here
       .....
       mClickListener = clickListener;
    }

    ......
    // rest of the code here
    ......

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FooHolder holder, int position) {
       // rest of the code

      holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mClickListener != null) {
                        mClickListener.onClick(name.getText().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    // other codes here

    public interface RvClickListener {
        void onClick(String name);
    }

}
```

Now it's time to the adapter in our Fragment class. You need to change the code as below.

```
public class FooFragment extends Fragment {

  // other codes here

  // before setting adapter to RecyclerView make these changes.

    FooAdapter adapter = new FooAdapter(
                                    <other parameters>,
                                     new RvClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                          public void onClick(String name) {
                                             // do whatever you want
                                          }
                                  });
}
```