# Sliding Tabs: How to pass variables to multiple tab activities

Tags: java, android, variables, tabs

I have a MainActivity that compute 3 number results (double A, B, C) and 3 number results (double D, E, F) when a "compute" button is press. I then create a Sliding tab activity with 2 tabs to display the results. What I am trying to do is pass the variable (A, B, C) to be print in TextView of Tab-1; and pass the variables (D, E, F) to be print in TextView of Tab-2.

Where can I place the code, shown below to the MainActivity, to pass the variables to Tab-1 and Tab-2? Can anyone help or maybe I have used the wrong variable passing method? Thank you for your help.

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, form_tab1.class );
intent1.putExtra(EX_A, A);
intent1.putExtra(EX_B, B);
intent1.putExtra(EX_C, C);

Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, form_tab2.class );
intent2.putExtra(EX_D, D);
intent2.putExtra(EX_E, E);
intent2.putExtra(EX_F, F);
```

Here's the code of the MainActivity java:

```
package com.abc.www.apps;
import ...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EX_A = "com.abc.www.apps.EX_A";
    public static final String EX_F = "com.abc.www.apps.EX_B";
    public static final String EX_C = "com.abc.www.apps.EX_C";
    public static final String EX_D = "com.abc.www.apps.EX_D";
    public static final String EX_E = "com.abc.www.apps.EX_E";
    public static final String EX_F = "com.abc.www.apps.EX_F";

    double ax, bx, cx, dx;
    double A, B, C;
    double D, E, F;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ax = 2;
        bx = 3;
        cx = 4;
        dx = 5
    }

    //Compute button is pressed
    public void compute(View view)
    {
        A = ax+bx;
        B = ax+cx;
        C = ax+dx;
        D = bx+cx;
        E = bx+dx;
        F = cx+dx;

        //Open the Sliding Tab Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SlideTabActivity.class );
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here's the code of sliding tab activity:

```
package com.abc.www.apps;
import ...
public class SlideTabActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   /**
    * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
    * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
    * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
    * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
    * may be best to switch to a
    * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
    */
   private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
   public TextView outTV;

   /**
    * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
    */
   private ViewPager mViewPager;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.slidetab_form);

      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

      // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
      // primary sections of the activity.
      mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

      // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
      mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
      mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

      TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

      mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
      tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
   }

   /**
    * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
    */
   public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
      /**
       * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
       * fragment.
       */
      private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

      public PlaceholderFragment() {
      }

      /**
       * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
       * number.
       */
      public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
         PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
         Bundle args = new Bundle();
         args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
         fragment.setArguments(args);
         return fragment;
     }

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = null;
         switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
         {
            case 1:
               // do something
               rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_tab1, container, false);
               break;
            case 2:
               // load another page
               rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_tab2, container, false);
               break;
         }
         return rootView;
      }
   }

   /**
    * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
    * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
    */
   public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

      public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
         super(fm);
      }

      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
      // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
       return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
         // Show 2 total pages.
         return 2;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Look into this, this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46828366/8448886

Answer (score 0):

```
    send all variables to slidetabactivity and get all values there

    public void compute(View view)
        {
            A = ax+bx;
            B = ax+cx;
            C = ax+dx;
            D = bx+cx;
            E = bx+dx;
            F = cx+dx;

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, SlideTabActivity.class );
    intent1.putExtra(EX_A, A);
    intent1.putExtra(EX_B, B);
    intent1.putExtra(EX_C, C);
    intent1.putExtra(EX_D, D);
    intent1.putExtra(EX_E, E);
    intent1.putExtra(EX_F, F);

            //Open the Sliding Tab Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SlideTabActivity.class );
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    then create a two bundle variables in slidetabActivity 
Bundle tab1=new Bundle();
tab1.putdouble(EX_A, A);
tab1.putdouble(EX_B, B);
tab1.putdouble(EX_C, C);
Bundle tab2=new Bundle();
tab2.putdouble(EX_D, D);
tab2.putdouble(EX_E, E);
tab2.putdouble(EX_F, F);

    and pass different bundle to different tab  according to your condition`enter code here`
```

Comment: Mohit Hooda, Maybe I don't get want you are try to show me... when I created two bundle variables in the slidetabActivity, the "key string" and "variable  can not be resolve. Maybe you could show me an example?

Comment: You have to create two fragments for each tab first of all then you have to set bundle for each tab 
That's why I have created two separate bundle variables for each tab
Create newInstance method in each method and pass bundle in it so that you can fetch values from bundle in fragment

Comment: I have created them... its called form_tab1 and form_tab2. It is shown in the codes above in the onCreate() of the SlideTab. They contain nothing more than the onCreate() in the java file and TextView"s" in the xml file.

Comment: Just create static newInstance method in your fragment class and pass bundle in it and fetch bundle in oncrrateview of your fragment

Comment: Mohit, thank for replying. Maybe I am not getting it and I am new to creating android apps. Could you should by code example?